# How make Visual Studio make programs with 1252 encoding?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I have a solution on my Visual Studio and my program's language is Brazillian Portuguese.
Everytime I compile it and execute and it simply doesn't show the characters I wrote.

Example:
`int main (void) {

    printf("áéíóúàèìòù");

    return 0;

}`

It simply shows something really strange.

Although, I had tested another time taking the output to a file and it showed the right output, so I think the problem might be in the `cmd`.

Then, I searched what might be causing the problem and the results were hanging basically on the code page cmd used.

I finally used `chcp 1252`, but it seems it doens't work with me, so here I am. Does anyone know what code page should I use or what I can do to the source file to it show the right output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming C++.

The reason is that the file is saved with UTF-8 encoding, and the string literals are treated as a sequence of bytes.

So if you have `"é"` in your source code, it's treated as `"\c9\a9"` and it gets displayed in CP-437 (default Western encoding for Windows Command Prompt) as `├⌐`

Solution: either:

- save your source files in some 8-bit encoding (for example CP-1252), change the default encoding in VS, and set the terminal to use the same encoding,
- or change your terminal to something that support UTF-8, like Cygwin.